# How can I specify certain quantiles for renderer classification?

Tags: qgis, classification

For graduated classification in QGIS 2.0.1, I can choose between several statistical methods to classify my data (standard deviation, quantile, natural breaks...) and for each method it is possible to choose the number of classes.

How can I choose the range limits for each class? In other words, choosing the quantile method, can I set each class border to be, for example, the 20th, 40th, 60th and 80th quantile rather than 25th, 50th, 75th and 95th?

It seems that QGIS calculates automatically the class range limits but it is not possible to know the corresponding quantile.

Comment: 8 years later and i also haven't found a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the range manually by double clicking on the Value you want to change

[image: editing value]